# Android Studio Spinner doesn't react to click

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have a `Spinner` in my fragment but when I **click the spinner** I don't get the actual **dropdown list** to show

Here is the java for my `Spinner`

```
 private void createCommissionDropDownList(){
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mReportViewModel.getCommissionNames());
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_my_spinner_item);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) mBaseLayout.findViewById(R.id.commissionSpinner);
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int itemId = (int) id;

               if(itemId == 0) {
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(), mReportViewModel.getCommissionNames().size() + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

Here is my xml for the `Spinner`

```
     <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/commissionSpinner"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

The image below shows how it looks like

[image]

The yellow is the actual spinner, it does not respond to my clicks however

I call my method to create the spinner in my `onCreateView` as shown below.
I have logged and made toasts to make sure it is being called as well.

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mBaseLayout = (PercentRelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report, container, false);
    mShift = getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableExtra("shift");


    if(mShift.getDate().isAfter(DateAndTime.getDateToday())) {
        displayCantReportReason("Du kan inte tidsrapportera ett pass som är i framtiden");
    } else {


        if (mShift.isNewShift()) {
            mReportViewModel = new ReportViewModel(null, null, new DataLoaderCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onDataLoaded() {
                    createForm();
                }
            });
        } else {
            mReportViewModel = new ReportViewModel(mShift.getCommissionId(), mShift.getDate(), new DataLoaderCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onDataLoaded() {
                    createForm();
                }
            });
        }

    }

    return mBaseLayout;
}

public void createForm() {


    if(mShift.isNewShift()){
        createCommissionDropDownList();
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Try this `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: @FiN tried, no further success

Comment: Please remove this...`android:visibility="gone`

Comment: @FiN i need it to be gone, however, i gave it a try anyway to see if it was the cause, unfortunately the problem remains the same

Comment: Are you sure that `getContext()` is returning an activity context? Try calling `getActivity()` instead.

Comment: @Pztar tried changing, no success

Comment: Where are you calling this method from? Would you mind sharing that?

Comment: I am making data requests in the onCreateView and depending on the result I get back call this method to give the user an oppurtunity to choose what he/she wants to work with. I am sure it is being called however, I have logged, made Toasts and other stuff to make sure.

Comment: @Pztar i updated the post with the code where I call the method

Comment: I'm really not sure. Try adding a `Log.i("Spinner", mReportViewModel.getCommissionNames().size() + "")` right after setting your adapter? Then check the logcat output to see if the size > 0. If your list contains no items your `Spinner` won't show.

Comment: I got it to work, looks like my spinner was interfering with my scrollview, i had to set my scrollview below my spinner and then it registered the click event